# Nullpointer with navigation drawer. Not detecting value assignments

Tags: android, navigation, null-pointer

I'm trying to create a navigation drawer, but I keep getting a NullPointer error. When I debugged it, the `ListView` and `DrawerLayout` values were null, even though I assign them their respective values. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<String> mTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> mUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> mAbstract = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> mDrawerTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
public ListView mDrawerList;

ProgressDialog progressDialog;


public final String TOPSTORYKEY = "878029f7fee45ecd61ca3f52ea027186:19:72302140";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerTitles.add("Politics");
    mDrawerTitles.add("Technology");
    mDrawerTitles.add("Sports");
    mDrawerTitles.add("Books");

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    //DrawerListAdapter drawerAdapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mDrawerTitles);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerTitles));

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    //new HttpJSONLoader().execute();

}
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

EDIT: here is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:text="No results"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: @N1to gone ahead and added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Solution was moving DrawerLayout from `drawer_layout.xml` to `activity_main.xml` and making layout have only two children, where first is MainActivity UI, and second is navigation drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
           android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:text="No results" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
       android:layout_width="240dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:background="#111"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
       android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

---

---

You need to set proper id in your XML for your `ListView` - `android:id="@+id/left_drawer"`, which is the same as id are you referring in `OnCreate`, it causes your error.

Anyway, your implementation is wrong. Please read how to do it properly.

Here it is great explained how to do this - [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">



<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No results"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Comment: I do set the proper id in the `mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);` line don't I?

Comment: No. In your xml you set `android:id="@android:id/list"`, while in code you want find this view by id `left_drawer`, not `list`. So you must change in xml to `android:id="@+id/left_drawer"`

Comment: In the rest of my project I am pulling and parsing a json response that populates the main activity in a list view. The listview that I am using for the drawer is in a `drawer_layout.xml` file. Regardless, i wouldn't be getting a nullpointer error for both of the mentioned values.

Comment: Look. You are setting layout for MainActivity using function `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `onCreate`. Then you are trying to get reference to widget `mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);` . It starts searching for item with id `left_drawer` in `activity_main.xml`, but it won't find because it does not exist in this layout.

Comment: So originally my `drawer_layout` wasn't in my `activity_main` which I discovered had to be. I put it in there so now I have both `ListViews`, the one that populates the main layout and the one that populates the drawer layout. Still get the same error though.

Comment: DrawerLayout only supports two child views.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82344/discussion-between-n1to-and-ralphie9224).